# Find value of an array based off form select values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically i have a custom form with a simple user fill then they select the amount of users and amount of products they want. I am then trying to pull the values of an array as shown below to produce a # result in an input field which i will also submit with the form.

Below is what i have so far;

```
var arraymultidimensional = []
arraymultidimensional = [[$200,$250],[$300,$350],[$400,$450]];
```

Result:

position 0 [$200][$250]
position 1 [$300][$350]
position 2 [$400][$450]

This part i get so far, but what i am trying to do here is if a client were to select 2 users and 2 products, based off the above i would like to display $350 in the input field but i am unsure how to select this value within the array based off a 'count' type system for the position in the array.

Reason for it to be fluid like this is as there are more products available, there will also be more prices added so the array will get a little larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ended up working this out.**

Based off the comments made by Ankit Agarwal here are my workings in case someone else needs this solution and comes across this post. Hopefully this can help someone else!

```
        var price = [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
            [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
            [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
            [41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
            [51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
        ];

        $(document).on("change click", ".form-control", function() {
            var productsum = 0;
            var usersum = 0;

            $(".fieldRow .form-control").each(function(){
                productsum += +$(this).length;
            });

            $(".userinput").each(function(){
                usersum += +$(this).val();
            });

            $(".products-amount").text(numbersum);
            $(".users-quantity").text(usersum);
            $('#total').text(price[usersum][productsum]);
        });
```

Basically... Based off what a user selects from two different fields, one being 'users' and one being 'products' it will select a different price value from the multi array i have setup.

The main reason for it being in an array such as this is it will be updated on a regular basis and it allows to be fluid based on selected values.

If you wish to have a free type numeric field you would want to change the following so it will capture the release of the keystroke and capture the value.

```
$(document).on("change click keyup", ".form-control", function() {
```

P.S. Reason for doing a .length count on the 'productsum' is i am duplicating that select box with it's options for multiple product options. This can simply be replaced with .val() to grab the value associated with it.

I am still working on other elements of the page so this is not the finished product but a good start for someone else to modify for their own use!

Answer (score 1):

The array index always starts from `0` and since you have array or arrays for selecting item corresponds to 2 users and 2 products, you need to select `arraymultidimensional[1][1]`. Thus, for any input values you need to subtract that value by one and since it is a multidimensional array use `[][]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i ended up weaving it into my original code and came up with a neat solution. Need to clean it up but sharing the code in case someone else needs it and comes across this post.